# Configure multiple static IPv6 addresses with dynamic prefix

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6

is it possible to add *multiple* IP addresses to an interface where the host part is static and the prefix is dynamically determined from router advertisements?

All ressouces I found told me to set a token with `ip token set ::1a:2b:3c:4d/64 dev eth0`. But this does not apply here because it affects only the primariy address generated by SLAAC.

I have the idea to setup virtual interfaces and set the token on them but that looks very ugly to me.

*If your answer contains code, it would be nice to use iproute2/netplan but I appreciate ifconfig examples, too. ;)*

---

**Update:**

Michael asked what my *real problem* was. Actually, I don't have one. The question arose out of academic interest. I had the idea to dig into IPv6 and while I was playing arround, this question came to my mind. I researched, read quite a bit and couldn't find an answer. The only hint that came close to this was the token.
If there were a solution it might have been of interest at home or when using provisioning scripts to setup server clones in different subnets.

Comment: What is [the real problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912) you are trying to solve, that led you to this as a possible solution? It won't work, so you need to talk about the actual problem.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thank you for your time, @MichaelHampton!

Comment: We're all about automation these days. (And we always were.) Dumping automation to go back to manual processes is usually a non-starter. This is probably why the IPv6 token I-D never actually became an RFC.

Comment: I have the same question, hopefully someone knows how to add additional ipv6 addresses to an interface.

Comment: @SaudIqbal This question is about adresses with dynamic prefixes and most likely not what you are looking for.